# JAVA перевод байтового потока в char unicode

Tags: java, unicode, char

Вопрос по поводу байтового чтения данных из консоли.

Например вводим букву "Я". В unicode "Я" равняется числу 1071.
При байтовом чтении буквы "Я" мы получаем 2 числа: 208 и 175.

```
// input "Я"
while (true) {
   int x = System.in.read();
   System.out.println(x);
}
```

208 - 11010000, 175 - 10101111

Символьное чтение

```
// input "Я"
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
while (true) {
   int x = reader.read();
   System.out.println(x);
}
```

```
char x = 1071;
System.out.println(x); // Я
```

Русские символы занимают 2 байта в памяти.

Каким образом при переводе байтов в char получается 1071 ? Кто может раписать расчет?

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: Русские символы занимают 2 байта в памяти — если я правильно помню, в Java все символы занимают два байта в памяти, так что это странное утверждение.

Comment: Первые 3 бита в первом байте и первые 2 во втором незначащие, это часть [кодировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Если их вычеркнуть, оставшиеся биты дадут 1071